# Simplify mysql union query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this query, which is slow.  I get the count of each select and define them as columns `free_cnt`,`plus_cnt`, so I can manipulate in the parent select query.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT movie_title,movie_id,MAX(x.free_cnt) as free_cnt, MAX(x.plus_cnt) as plus_cnt, ((MAX(x.free_cnt)*1) + (MAX(x.plus_cnt)*3)) AS score, (MAX(x.free_cnt) + MAX(x.plus_cnt)) AS total
            FROM (
                SELECT b.id as movie_id, b.movie_title as movie_title, COUNT(*) AS free_cnt, 0 as plus_cnt
                FROM preview_movie_request a1
                LEFT JOIN movies b on a1.movie_id=b.id
                JOIN users c on c.email=a1.email
                WHERE c.subsc_status='0' AND c.package_type='' AND b.movie_type=2 $where1
                GROUP BY b.movie_title
                UNION ALL

                SELECT d.id as movie_id, d.movie_title as movie_title,  0 as free_cnt, COUNT(*) AS plus_cnt
                FROM preview_movie_request a2
                LEFT JOIN movies d on a2.movie_id=d.id
                JOIN users e on e.email=a2.email
                WHERE e.subsc_status='1' AND e.package_type!='' AND d.movie_type=2 $where2
                GROUP BY d.movie_title
                UNION ALL

            ) AS x
            GROUP BY movie_title
            $orderby
            $limit");
```

Is there anyway to simplify query and make faster?

Comment: What is it in order by and LIMIT ?

Comment: This appears to be adhoc. Where the user decides which columns to sort on, how many results are wanted and any additional filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate one subquery moving the count conditions in case

```
SELECT movie_title,movie_id,MAX(x.free_cnt) as free_cnt, MAX(x.plus_cnt) as plus_cnt, ((MAX(x.free_cnt)*1) + (MAX(x.plus_cnt)*3)) AS score, (MAX(x.free_cnt) + MAX(x.plus_cnt)) AS total FROM
(
SELECT b.id as movie_id, b.movie_title as movie_title,
 SUM(CASE WHEN c.subsc_status='0' AND c.package_type='' AND b.movie_type=2 $where1 THEN 1 END ) AS free_cnt,
 SUM(CASE WHEN c.subsc_status='1' AND c.package_type!='' AND b.movie_type=2  $where2 THEN 1 END ) AS  plus_cnt,

                FROM preview_movie_request a1
                LEFT JOIN movies b on a1.movie_id=b.id
                JOIN users c on c.email=a1.email

                GROUP BY b.movie_title)x    
GROUP BY movie_title
$orderby
$limit
```

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN bool THEN 1 END)` can be simplified to `SUM(bool)`